# How to do video streaming with a canon EOS M?

Tags: streaming, canon

What software is needed to do video capture from a Canon EOS M?
How can I use the Canon EOS M as a Webcam?
Thank you,

Answer (score 1):

There's a couple ways I know of to do this that might work depending on what you need.  The first way would be to use an HDMI capture card like the Blackmagic Intensity.  The second way would be to use the Canon EOS utility over USB.

Comment: In the Canon EOS Utility SW from the EOS M there is no way to set the camera as a Webcam. Or at least I haven been able to find how to do it. Thank you for your help.

Comment: There should be an option for live video monitoring. This may or may not do what you need.

Answer (score 0):

I hooked up the EOS-M via USB and turned it on.

No, there is no option for video monitoring in the EOS Utility.

I will go buy a $70 webcam to do this.

PS Recording separately as the first poster recommended will record a podcast. It does not allow using the EOS-M as a Webcam.